# Setting Margin in C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

How can I set the Margin of a control in WPF? I used to use WinForms and am looking to make the conversion to WPF.

So, I made a new WPF application, deleted the Grid off MainWindow, added a Canvas, and added two Labels on the Canvas. I want to set a Margin around the labels but once I set it, say to 20, and then try to move them to check to see if it worked, the Margin property of Label resets the values to 0. Can I still do this in WPF like I could in WinForms?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Hopefully this is the code that's of interest.

So, I change the Label's Margin values in the Property tab. Looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="173" Margin="87,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" Canvas.Left="51" Canvas.Top="47" Margin="20"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" Canvas.Left="104" Canvas.Top="125" Margin="20"/>
</Canvas></Window>
```

Then, I drag a Label and it automatically changes to this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="173" Margin="87,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" Canvas.Left="51" Canvas.Top="47" Margin="20"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" Canvas.Left="129" Canvas.Top="101"/>
</Canvas> </Window>
```

If I drag the other Label, it too "resets" to zero.

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: @AliTor Sure, what specifically would you like to see? The generated XAML?

Comment: Are you moving the labels in WPF Designer?

Comment: @Cyferka Yes, I am.

Comment: @jon, Welcome to WPF.  As a recovering Winforms addict myself, I can tell you that the WPF paradigm will make no sense at first.  Once you get used to it, though, you'll never go back.  You need to ditch the Canvas and Labels and go back to the Grid that was supplied and check out the TextBlock controls instead of Labels. Grid is for holding controls, Canvas is really only for drawing (lines and circles and such).

Comment: @Stewbob Ah, I figured this would be the case. :D Ok, I think I'll get started on some reading/tutorials: can you suggest any resources for WPF beginners (books, online, whatever)? [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22980/WPF-A-Beginner-s-Guide-Part-of-n) looks like a place to start.

Comment: @jon, yes.  Good place to start.  I recommend Sacha Barber.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is when a Label is inside a Canvas. I added the example with the Grid and it works as expected, the Margin property is recalculated when a Label is moved.

```
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
</Grid>
```

Alternatively, you can use a Padding property if that would work for you. No matter how you move the Label it would stay at 20.

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="173" Margin="87,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="21" Padding="20"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" Canvas.Left="32" Canvas.Top="125"/>
</Canvas>
```

However, I would strongly recommend editing only the source code and do not touch the elements in WPF Designer. You will gain much more control over your code.